# Get bottom panel back

Tags: panel, gui, awn

I'm trying [Avant Window Navigator](http://awn-project.org/)(AWN) and I would like to delete my bottom panel to test only the AWN.

But, if I don't like it, is there a way to get my bottom panel back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if required later you can  reset the gnome panel, intructions available at [Resetting gnome panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41/resetting-gnome-panel) .