# Where does GNOME 3 store panel orientation?

Tags: 11.10, configuration, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

What file does Gnome3 (without Unity) store the top/bottom panel "orientation" settings in? This sort of thing used to be available in the `gconf-editor` under `apps/panel`, but there doesn't seem to be anything about panel orientation there anymore. Where can I find it?

I don't even have a `~/.gconf/apps/panel` directory, so I can't reset as described in [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41/resetting-gnome-panel) (probably Gnome2 info). I have `~/.gconf/apps/panel3-applets` and `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel`, but neither of them has anything about panel orientation (the former just has applet config, as you'd expect; the latter just has a `%gconf.xml` containing only run history). I even removed my `~/.gconf` directory entirely (well, okay, I renamed it) and rebooted, no change. Clearly not stored in there. Nor in `~/.gconfd`.

Background: I moved everything to one panel (prefer not having top and bottom), then thought I'd try docking it to the left to see what that was like. What it's like is: Non-functional. When I first log in it shows, but trying to do anything with it makes it disappear. Unfortunately, one of the things that makes it disappear is trying to access the Properties dialog to dock it somewhere else...

---

**Update:** Okay, this is just weird. First I looked at all files changed under my home directory at about the time I made the change. No luck. So allowing for some poor programming, I've now looked at the name of every file found by the following command issued from the root of my file system:

```
find . -mmin -450 -mmin +240 -type f -not \( -wholename "*/home/tjc/.cache*" -o -wholename "*/home/tjc/.thumbnails*" -o -wholename "*/var/lib/dpkg/info*" \) -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %p \n" | sort > ~/changed
```

...which did (when I ran it) encompass the relevant timeframe (and quite a bit on either side), and for any file that looked like it could *possibly* contain this setting, I've opened that file and looked at it. Not a thing.

That leaves us with the *absense* of a setting defaulting to "dock left," which makes no sense at all.

I took a backup earlier (because I was going to be doing a lot of things to my system, mostly because I've given up on Unity, which is a great idea and may well get there in the end, but is just way too buggy / feature poor for prime time use yet). If I'd realized it was going to be this hard to undo this stoopid little docking setting, I'd've restored that backup 90 minutes ago. Crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings for GNOME Panel are stored in dconf, now, and you can access them using [dconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/dconf-tools/) under: `/org/gnome/gnome-panel`.

Stuff in dconf is stored in a binary format, which is why those options didn't show up in a search.

**To run dconf-editor:**

- First install dconf-tools:

  - `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` or click [here (apt://dconf-tools)](http://apt://dconf-tools).
- Then run `dconf-editor`.

**Screenshot:**
[image: dconf-editor]

Comment: Perfect! Sadly I'd already restored my previous backup, but when I removed Unity again I installed dconf-editor and verified that it was exactly what I would have needed. (In fact, having checked that I could use `dconf-editor` to move the panel from top to bottom and back, I tested this by putting the panel on the left. It promptly crashed, and I used `dconf-editor` to fix it.) Nice one, thanks!

Comment: (We should clean up the out-of-date comments. I've removed mine.)