# remove top and bottom gnome panels in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

**Background :**

I developed a python desktop application which is run on the top of Ubuntu 12.04 and it is running in full screen mode. I used `gnome-fallback` as a Ubuntu Desktop.

**Question :**

My problem is delete top and bottom Gnome panels permanently and I know how to do it from gui itself (ALT + Right Click). But I need to do it from the commands.

Anyone have an idea about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which desktop are you using?  Are you using gnome-fallback ?

Comment: I use gnome-fallback

Comment: I'm curious, does [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/410311/44179) do what you want or are you looking for something else?

Comment: You are running *pure* Ubuntu 12.04? i.e. Not elementary OS, Mint or something else?

Comment: What kind of python app are you writing? You can install Openbox if you only need an "empty" desktop to play/test :-)

Comment: @Seth that is pure Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
@edwin that is python based video capturing software, but for the hardening purpose I remove all OS functionalists, even `nautilus`. Anyway Ill try 'Openbox' also.

Comment: When you run my gsettings command *nothing* happens? I understand why the change isn't persistent, but I have no clue why nothing would happen. I think I know a workaround though which I will test soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Backup your panel configuration:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/gnome-panel/ > /some/location/backup.xml
```

Now remove the panels:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list [""]
```

If you want to restore them later use:

```
cat /some/location/backup.xml | dconf load /org/gnome/gnome-panel/
```

NOTE: This doesn't seem to hold after a reboot. Further research shows this is because several dconf schemas are still in place. I have yet to figure out how to remove these.

Comment: I tried your commands , it was not given any errors but no results also.

Comment: @JanithChinthana What do you mean by "no results"? Just nothing happens?

Comment: panels not removed. then I tried with restart also. but still same results. But I check the `dconf-editor`, it shows that `toplevel-id-list` is empty. but actually its not removed from the desktop.
anyway +1 for `toplevel-id-list [""]`

Comment: One more thing, I change those settings manually(Alt+Right Click) earlier to see what are the changes to be appeared in dconf. Im not sure that might be the issue. As per the @Lorenzo 's comment we should do this for fresh instance.

Comment: @Janith Are you using gnome - fallback-no-effects or just gnome-fallback?

Comment: @JanithChinthana Upon more research, it seems that 12.04 does this differently than 13.10 (which I use). I'll look into it.

Comment: `gnome-fallback`

Comment: @JanithChinthana Alright. I'm working on fixing it for 12.04 right now.

Comment: @JanithChinthana After more testing, my original answers works fine for me on 12.04.3... Can you show me a screenshot of your desktop after you run the command?

Comment: from the very beginning I face same issue(after restart it appears again), then I remove all the objects in the panel before removing the panel itself, then it works for me. but finally one of empty panel remain in the Desktop which I can't remove anyway.

Comment: @Janith A screenshot would help immensely.

Comment: I can't share screen-shot due to some reasons, but it is like this now, http://kevin.herrera.io/assets/posts/2013-06-04-ubuntu-gnome-panel/panel-menu.png
top panel has removed and empty bottom panel stay same. but it doesn't have any objects.

Comment: ill offer bounty for your try even its not 100% working

Comment: This does not work in Gnome 3

Comment: @Wild No it doesn't. Gnome-flashback and gnome 3 are very different. I'm not sure what you hope to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I fixed my problem. Understanding gnome 3 and gnome flash back are different, they use separate config files, etc was important.

Answer (score 1):

The settings [are stored in dconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78240/where-does-gnome-3-store-panel-orientation): you should use `dconf-editor` (from `dconf-tools`) to find them and the **[GSettings API](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/GSettings.html)** to edit them from your script/software.

Good programming and comment under here if you have more questions or problems. ;-D

Comment: I found the `top-panel` and `bottom-panel` under the `dconf-editor`, but i couldn't find a way how to remove them from the commands

Comment: It may vary from version to version. I've done some research, as there aren't common procedures.
Let's try: org>gnome>gnome-panel>layout>"toplevel-id-list" and edit the entry by removing both panels names. Restart gnome and they should disappear.
To do this from GSettings you need to adapt your entire application. :-( There is a guide for Python and GSettings, read it and see if it can help: http://www.micahcarrick.com/gsettings-python-gnome-3.html
Don't copy-paste in your existing script, try it directly in a new application before editing the current things. Let us know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can make your own session without gnome bars. I made my own session with awn, I login to my session without gnome panel. There is a tutorial in below link about how to do it. I must warn you about hidden .desktop extension files in  "/usr/share/xsessions/" Nautilus blind to such extension due to a bug, There would be "~" ended backup files that confuses you. I stuck in login screen once due to picking up wrong file. I advise you to use command line ls to list folder entries. You are warned. 
 [Link](http://artipc10.vub.ac.be/wordpress/2012/03/04/creating-your-own-gnome-session-based-on-cairo-dock-and-compiz/)

Answer (score 0):

install dconf-tools

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

open the program by

`dconf-editor`

go to Desktop-->Unity-->Panel

if you want to add a prgram add that

,'program name'

and this program make you edit in gnome