# gnome-panel has multiple rows -- how to undo that?

Tags: gnome-panel

On Ubuntu 12.04 I use openbox with a single "gnome-panel" started. But after trying to configure my two screen in Xinerama mode I got **additional rows of panels** each time X restarted.

And despite I completely reverted to my one-screen-X-config

- the `gnome-panel` displayed has 4 rows (4 at top sreen, 4 at bottom)
- only the outermost row has content, the other 3 are empty
- there is only one gnome-panel process running
- some widgets appear 4 times, too, although they run only once
- when I switch away from openbox using unity I am back to 1 row temporarily

What went wrong here? How do I undo that? Things that did *not* help:

- `rm -Rf .gnome2 .gconf/ .compiz-1/`
- `pkill panel`, and restarting it

Comment: This is bug in gnome-panel, at least i think so. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/1083811

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run the following, apparently gnome3 stores configuration in binary form (I haven't read up on dconf enough to know where or why).

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Run: `dconf-editor` to edit the config.

Go to: `org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout` (it's pretty intuitive)

The defaults seem to be:

```
object-id-list     ['menu-bar', 'indicators', 'show-desktop', 'window-list', 'workspace-switcher']
toplevel-id-list   ['top-panel', 'bottom-panel']
```

I had to figure this out after I had some weird issue with gnome while trying to get my 2 monitors to work.  Everything (menus, rows, clock, etc.) seemed to duplicate on the panel after every attempt to restart the X server.  I should have took a screenshot but this is essentially what I had before I fixed it:

```
object-id-list     ['menu-bar', 'indicators', 'show-desktop', 'window-list', 'workspace-switcher', 'menu-bar-0', 'indicators-0', 'show-desktop-0', 'window-list-0', 'workspace-switcher-0', 'menu-bar-1', 'indicators-1', 'show-desktop-1', 'window-list-1', 'workspace-switcher-1']
toplevel-id-list   ['top-panel', 'bottom-panel', 'top-panel-screen1', 'bottom-panel-screen1', 'top-panel-screen1-0', 'bottom-panel-screen1-0']
```

As you can see, there's 3 of everything.

Comment: That was a perfect solution and nicely described. Do you happen to know where the config is stored that I am editing with `dconf-editor`? a) I could edit that file with emacs, then and b) I have most files of my homdir in a git repository and thought I would be safe against such things now -- but it seems I missed the file where that is stored.

Comment: I found this, but I don't have a $DCONF_PROFILE and I haven't been able to find the files, hope this helps:  http://live.gnome.org/dconf/SystemAdministrators

Comment: your settings work, but note that clicking the "Set to default" leaves the value blank (`[]`) (at least on my 12.10)

Comment: pkill gnome-panel and blank values will be magically restored.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to zechariah.

What about:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/
```

That got rid of 3 of my four panels.

Comment: The multiple rows came back for me every time gnome-panel was started.  This turned out to be because /etc/X11/xorg.conf defined an extra "screen".