# Duplicated menu, panel indicators and taskbar

Tags: nvidia, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gnome-panel has multiple rows — how to undo that?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133647/gnome-panel-has-multiple-rows-how-to-undo-that)

Ubuntu 12.04.  The first time I log into Gnome Classic I get a duplicate of every menu, panel indicator and taskbar entry.  If I log out and back in again I now have three copies.  Log out and log in, four copies and so forth.

[image: Desktop showing four instances of menus and taskbar]

What would cause this?  I can't see any obvious duplicates in the process list:

```
$ ps -A | grep 'gno\|org\|nau'
27439 tty7     00:00:18 Xorg
27610 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
27621 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session
27674 ?        00:00:00 gnome-settings-
27709 ?        00:00:07 gnome-panel
27720 ?        00:00:00 gnome-fallback-
27726 ?        00:00:04 nautilus
27736 ?        00:00:00 polkit-gnome-au
28281 ?        00:00:00 gnome-screensav
29016 ?        00:00:00 gnome-terminal
29021 ?        00:00:00 gnome-pty-helpe
```

If it helps, I was recently trying the Nouveau drivers but have now reverted to NVIDIA.  Configuration is Separate X Window, Xinerama enabled.  Unity is fine, so the problem is limited to the Classic desktop.

I haven't had any luck googling these particular symptoms so any tips would be really appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. I finally found a solution. Follow the instructions on the answer. You can double click inside the [ ] to edit what you need.

[gnome-panel has multiple rows -- how to undo that?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133647/gnome-panel-has-multiple-rows-how-to-undo-that)