# Double entries in the gnome 3 task bar

Tags: 12.04, ati, gnome-panel, fglrx

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome 3. All was working well except that graphics were slow and even moving a window on the screen seemed slow.

I installed the `fglrx` ati driver. Which seems to have improved matters. But on first login I had all gnome items duplicated. That is my task bar has the ubuntu sign, then says Applications, then places then the ubuntu sign then Aplications and then places.

Any application I run produces two icons at the bottom of the screen. This was after a reboot. I rebooted again. Now I have 3!! On the right each set of icons such as printer is also trippled!!

See **screenshot** at http://jetmark.co.uk/Screenshot.png
See **Dmesg** at http://jetmark.co.uk/dmesg.txt

Any suggestions welcome.

Reboot -> now I have 4!! So one set gets added on each reboot. Help!! I am going to be task barred out before long!!

Does no one have any suggestions at all? Or suggestions about where to look ?

This looks very like bug 650154 at bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650164,

But this bug is closed obsolete. And not only that the code referred to in the fix, in file 
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/appDisplay.js line 129 is completely different to that quoted.

So is this a regression?

Still no comment from this board. I am up to 6 instances now, have lost my application menu since its covered by the other stuff.

So, I make a file, then reboot and immediately after reboot, do a find to find all files newer than the file just made.

This comes up with more than 100000 file, wow. Whittling them down a bit, the following seemed suspicious:

ls /home/mark/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles

Default  %gconf.xml  Profile0  Profile1  Profile2  Profile3

There were 5 duplicates at the time so this seemed suspicious.

I removed all directories beginning 'P' in the list above, so there was just Default and %gconf.xml which is empty. (Each of these contains a just one file %gconf.xml)

None of this helped at all. I am up to 7 instances.

## Update 18 Dec.

Still no solution.

I discovered that the problem utility is gnome-panel.

Running gnome-panel --replace gets me yet another set without even having to logout and in. I have 10 now.

I tried to reinstall gnome-panel and wow, all seemed good. There was an err, that unfortunatly I did not not.

I tried it again and I was back to many versions running.

Now I am unsure if I had one gnome-panels or none.

I can get rid of all of them by hitting control C on the4 (now) terminal that ran gnome-panel. Thats refreshing but not quite what I want.

Let me try this re-install and relaunch again ...

No, it didnt work 2nd time round.

Hmm. Control C out of that (as Now I just have too many gnome-panels visible to even leave the darned thing running.

If I run gnome-panel, no options as sudo, I am back to just 2, thats interesting. 
And thats also pretty refreshing after having more than 12.

Comment: I had the same issue and I solved it by follow the steps in zechariah's answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/133647/gnome-panel-has-multiple-rows-how-to-undo-that