# gnome-panel icons duplicated across multiple monitors

Tags: unity, gnome-panel

I ask this question, because search on AskUbuntu is not helped for me.

I have an issue:

[image: Imgur]

My panel icons is duplicated. I have one notebook monitor. These steps I did:

1. Reset settings in dconf: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/`
2. Found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/134058/177228) but it didn't solved my problem. Panel is still duplicated.

Unity version is 7.0.0, Ubuntu 13.04, Kernel 3.8.0-26-generic. What I did wrong?

In my `/etc/rc.local` I disabled my Radeon video adapter(because this videocard is not working fine(hardware issue)):

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

There are no errors while system loading, there are no errors in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, only debug information about loading display.

```
[+76.92s] DEBUG: Starting session ubuntu as user ikhrome
[+76.92s] DEBUG: Session 1462 running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+77.09s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
[+77.09s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+77.10s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
```

**NOTE**: sometimes everything is OK, but many times panel duplicated.
After boot, and sometimes after logout.

Notebook HP Pavilion g6 1263sr.

Please, don't swear me, I had this issue for 3-4 days, and Google didn't helped me. And, sorry for my English. Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 0):

*community wiki - OP had added the answer into their question*

I write it for people with the same problem.

The problem was not in Unity. Ubuntu thought, that I have two monitors: notebook and unknown. Because unknown monitor was overlayed some space on the notebook monitor, panels was duplicated.

**The solution:**

1. Go to "System settings", "Monitors", and drag out unknown monitor, until it not hide from gray field.
2. select your monitor, select default resolution(ex. "1366x768") and click "Apply".
3. now we can't do something in GUI, we go to TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
4. and reboot, by using `sudo shutdown -r now` command.

It works fine for me. Hope it help. Problem, maybe, raised because I disabled the Radeon video adapter.